# Как реализовать перенаправление?

Tags: html

У меня есть такой код:

```html
<div class="row">
  <form action="#" method="post" class="subscribe-form">
    <fieldset class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-3 col-sm-8">
      <input type="password" id="subscribe-email" placeholder="Вставьте свой ключ сюда">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="col-md-5 col-sm-4">
      <input type="submit" id="subscribe-submit" class="button white" value="Подтвердить">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Нужно, чтобы пользователь при вводе ключа и нажатия на кнопку Подтвердить, перенаправляло на

```
www.site.ru/check.php?key=тут данные которые ввел пользователь
```

Comment: В `action` укажите куда отправлять данные и измените метод отправки, если вы хотите передать значения в `GET`.

Comment: Передача пароля в GET запросе - плохая идея

Comment: Знаю что это плохая идея, но все-равно при вводе ключа в check.php?key=тут ключ, его не пустит на сайт, так как идет привязка ключа к IPу пользователя, который вводит ключ.
Можете предложить пример кода, как реализовать, что бы текст из формы парсился в перенаправление site.ru/check.php?key=сюда ключ, который парсится при вводе в форму

Comment: Даже если вы защитили свой скрипт, это опасно для пользователя. GET сохраняется в истории браузера.

Comment: Ну мне сейчас нужна помощь в реализации редиректа на страницу check.php?key=ключ, который пользователь введет в форме. Про защиту пользователя речи не идет. Спасибо конечно, но я нуждаюсь в другом

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

В `action` укажите куда отправлять данные и измените метод отправки, если вы хотите передать значения в `GET`:

```
<div class="row">
    <form action="check.php" method="get" class="subscribe-form">
        <fieldset class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-3 col-sm-8">
            <input type="password" name="key" id="subscribe-email" placeholder="Вставьте свой ключ сюда">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="col-md-5 col-sm-4">
            <input type="submit" id="subscribe-submit" class="button white" value="Подтвердить">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Далее в `check.php` проверяйте есть ли значение:

```
if (isset($_GET)) {
    var_dump($_GET['key']);
}
```

Comment: Благодарю, все верно. 
Как я и хотел